Support for adding Events/Sub-Activities to Workouts
I have been using @kingstinct/react-native-healthkit package for tracking workouts and syncing data with Apple HealthKit. My requirement is to also add sub-activities or workout events in a workout.
For example, during a triathlon, a user might want to record separate segments for the swimming, cycling, and running as parts of the workout in apple health. just like the workout activities section in the attached image below.
But unfortunately, this package has no such option. How can I add this functionality natively into this package?


Is that package on GitHub? Could you log a ticket to describe what you want? They may suggest that you raise a PR; would you be able to help with making these changes?

@kingstinct/react-native-healthkit
yes this package is on github and i would in making these changes
